# How to read Shape properties in Visio

Tags: c#, visio

```
namespace VisioEventsExample
 {
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Open up one of Visio's sample drawings.
            Application app = new Application();
            Document doc = app.Documents.Open(
                @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\visio content\1033\ASTMGT_U.VST");

            // Get the first page in the sample drawing.
            Page page = doc.Pages[1];

            // Start with the collection of shapes on the page and 
            // print the properties we find,
            printProperties(page.Shapes);
        }

        /* This function will travel recursively through a collection of 
         * shapes and print the custom properties in each shape. 
         * 
         * The reason I don't simply look at the shapes in Page.Shapes is 
         * that when you use the Group command the shapes you group become 
         * child shapes of the group shape and are no longer one of the 
         * items in Page.Shapes.
         * 
         * This function will not recursive into shapes which have a Master. 
         * This means that shapes which were created by dropping from stencils 
         * will have their properties printed but properties of child shapes 
         * inside them will be ignored. I do this because such properties are 
         * not typically shown to the user and are often used to implement 
         * features of the shapes such as data graphics.
         * 
         * An alternative halting condition for the recursion which may be 
         * sensible for many drawing types would be to stop when you 
         * find a shape with custom properties.
         */
        public static void printProperties(Shapes shapes)
        {
            // Look at each shape in the collection.
            foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
            {               
                // Use this index to look at each row in the properties 
                // section.
                short iRow = (short) VisRowIndices.visRowFirst;

                // While there are stil rows to look at.
                while (shape.get_CellsSRCExists(
                    (short) VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, 
                    iRow, 
                    (short) VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue,
                    (short) 0) != 0)
                {
                    // Get the label and value of the current property.
                    string label = shape.get_CellsSRC(
                            (short) VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, 
                            iRow,
                            (short) VisCellIndices.visCustPropsLabel
                        ).get_ResultStr(VisUnitCodes.visNoCast);

                    string value = shape.get_CellsSRC(
                            (short) VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, 
                            iRow,
                            (short) VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue
                        ).get_ResultStr(VisUnitCodes.visNoCast);

                    // Print the results.
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
                        "Shape={0} Label={1} Value={2}",
                        shape.Name, label, value));

                    // Move to the next row in the properties section.
                    iRow++;
                }

                // Now look at child shapes in the collection.
                if (shape.Master == null && shape.Shapes.Count > 0)
                    printProperties(shape.Shapes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I asked in the comments to this code has been removed.
so I created a new theme.

Help me. This code opens the document. The first page. But! Shape Not find on the sheet! I always iRow = 0. But! Shape is on a sheet! I myself have made ​​them in advance! In what may be the Problem?

Comment: I advise you to remove the Russian, it will attract down-votes since StackOverflow is an English Language site.

Comment: What version of Visio are you using?

Are you using the file "ASTMGT_U.VST" which was installed with Visio or a different file?

Comment: @saveenr: The person who asked the question may not be using Visio 10. They may have just copied the code from this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6274758/9182) and is trying to get it working. The phrase "I myself have made them in advance" in their question makes me think they are not using the file in code.

Comment: @PatLeahy - good catch! Sinlop, it will help if you can be more specific about which version of Visio you are using. I tried the code you provided with Visio 2010 and it worked correctly.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using Visio 2007.Yes. I'm using the code from this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6274758/9182).
Unfortunately, I can not use Visio 10. The code only for this version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the code which would prevent it from working in Visio 2007. You need to use a path to a file which contains shapes on the first page which have custom properties.